# Latex formulas and lists in Jupyter notebook markdown with VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, markdown, jupyter, html-lists

I need to place latex formulas in list. With markdown:

```
    <ol>
        <li> $x_1$  </li>
        <li> $x_2$  </li>
    </ol>
```

I get:

[image]

As you can see, latex is not applied. How to fix it or what are the alternative ways to realise list with latex formulas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Jupyter Lab 3.2.9 or Jupyter Notebook 6.4.8. How are you running  your notebook?

Comment: @Chris I use Visual Studio code addon for Jupyter Note book. But i try this at classic version in browser, and this markdown works correctly. So the problem is in VS code, thank you.

Comment: @Chis Do you know alternative way to create a list in markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Code seems to render this just fine if you use Markdown syntax for your list instead of HTML:

```
1. $x_1$
1. $x_2$
```

[image: Screenshot of VSCode's rendering]

Comment: I expected that, it will be displayed in one line... And it is if not write numbers with dot before.